# Can't include the JPEG_SUPPORT headers in a dlib cpp file

Tags: c++, c++11, jpeg, header-files, dlib

I was trying to compile a cpp file: the face-finder in dlib: http://dlib.net/face_detection_ex.cpp.html. But when I ran it, it said I had to include the libraries for jpg and  png files:

```
processing image /home/james/Work/Coding/Sources/Image/950.jpg

exception thrown!
Unable to load image in file /home/dave/Code/Resources/Images/500.jpg.
You must #define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT and link to libjpeg to read JPEG files.
Do this by following the instructions at http://dlib.net/compile.html.

Note that you must cause DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT to be defined for your entire project.
So don't #define it in one file. Instead, use a compiler switch like -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
so it takes effect for your entire application.
```

I tried to use the `-DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT` flag, and that failed, so I treid to define them in the file:

```
*/

#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
#define DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT

#include </home/james/dlib/image_io.h>
#include </home/james/dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include </home/james/dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include </home/james/dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

but that failed to compile:

```
james@james-Toshiba-Satellite-8505:~/Work/Coding/Cpp/Dlib/Examples$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -I.. ~/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 face_detection_ex.cpp -o face_detection_ex_2/tmp/ccVHitZj.o: In function `main':
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1c0d): undefined reference to `dlib::jpeg_loader::jpeg_loader(std::string const&)'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1d0a): undefined reference to `dlib::jpeg_loader::is_gray() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e3b): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::png_loader(std::string const&)'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f04): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_gray() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f23): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_gray() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f38): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_graya() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f59): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_graya() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f6e): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_rgb() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f83): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_rgb() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1f98): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_rgba() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1fad): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_rgba() const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2009): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x20b6): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x211c): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::~png_loader()'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x229a): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2587): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ea7): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::~png_loader()'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2fe9): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x30ac): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x313c): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x31c4): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::get_row(unsigned int) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please before ask a question read the error and suggestion messages that compiler and tools show you.

> About:
> exception thrown! Unable to load image in file
>   /home/dave/Code/Resources/Images/500.jpg. You must #define
>   DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT and link to libjpeg to read JPEG files. Do this by
>   following the instructions at http://dlib.net/compile.html.

Install libjpeg, libpng, etc. libraries and use them at compilation time to link the program. Please read the suggested page http://dlib.net/compile.html.

Before compile delete the preprocessor directives from your code if you have several source code files.

```
#define DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
#define DLIB_PNG_SUPPORT
```

and use the suggested switch compiler: -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT.

> Note that you must cause DLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT to be defined for your
>   entire project. So don't #define it in one file. Instead, use a
>   compiler switch like -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT so it takes effect for your
>   entire application.

So, use command like this to compile:

> g++ face_detection_ex.cpp -o face_detection_ex_2 -std=c++11 -O3 -I..
>   ~/dlib/all/source.cpp -lpthread -lX11 -ljpeg -lpng -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT
>   -DDLIB_PNG_SUPPORT

Assuming libraries (libjpeg and libpng) have been already installed.

Comment: I *tried* to define them, and they didn't work. I already have libjpeg and libpng installed.

Comment: When I tried to run your commmand, it said:  `g++: error: lpng: No such file or directory`

Comment: I forget a dash in the command, but it's has updated right now.
Change ( lpng -> -lpng ).